# Porting entire Java projects to to C#

Tags: java, c#, eclipse, porting, sharpen-tool

I'm looking for a free way to convert entire Java projects to C#. I followed [Pauldb's article on using Sharpen in eclipse.](http://web.archive.org/web/20130503135428/http://www.pauldb.me/post/14916717048/a-guide-to-sharpen-a-great-tool-for-converting-java) The tutorial is a bit outdated.

While using Luna on Windows I got the following errors:

After trying to update the references to work on my enviroment I get

```
...\run-sharpen.xml:59: The following error occurred while executing this line:
...\run-sharpen.xml:20: exec returned: 13
```

In which the log file says "java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "sharpen.core.application" could not be found in the registry."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Step 1:** Download eclipse Mars (I'm using 4.5.0)

**Step 2:** Open Eclipse. Import your project and use a src/ folder for all your java files.

**Step 3:** Add the files "sharpen.properties", "sharpen-all-options", "run-sharpen.xml" and "header.txt" to the root of the project folder. Edit sharpen.properties to fit your enviroment. In run-sharpen.xml, comment out these lines as they are examples for dependencies:

```
<arg value="-cp" />
<arg path="C:/eclipse/workspace/myproject/libs/kxml2-2.3.0.jar" />
<arg value="-cp" />
<arg path="C:/eclipse/workspace/myproject/libs/regexp-me.jar" />
```

**Step 4:** Help > Install new software > Find and add "Eclipse 2.0 Style Plugin Support" and "Eclipse e4 Tools Developer Resources" (or just search "Eclipse Tests, Tools, Examples, and Extras" and add all)

**Step 5:**: [Use ngit's sharpen.core jar file](https://github.com/mono/ngit/blob/master/gen/plugins/sharpen.core_1.0.0.jar) and place it into your "eclipse/plugins" folder.

**Step 6:** [mlink your "/Program%20Files/" to be "/Program Files/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140101/eclipse-mars-ant-task-references-missing-swt-library) I believe this is a bug in Mars. This prevents "org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.104.0.v20150528-0211.jar" cannot be found error (even when it exists).

**Step 7:** Run the Ant file in eclipse. It should tell you it compiled. Otherwise it will give you a link to

**Step 8:** Sharpen does a pretty good job but there will be errors. If an error is too common, edit "sharpen-all-options" and re-run.

---

**Notes:** I couldn't get this to work in Luna after too many hours of trying. Updated to Mars and it had different problems that I could fix. It wouldn't recognize ""sharpen.core.application" could not be found in the registry". Updating to mars seems to fix it.

[Link to example github project](https://github.com/TotzkePaul/JavaToCSharpPortExample)